# General python server

Tags: python, server

When I do this

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer
```

it serves on port 8000.

How to change the port to other than 8000, say I want 8001.

Sorry I'm really confused and need to finish a project, but my port 8000 isn't updating any of the files I save. Please help.

Comment: What do you mean by update? The files are hosted on a localhost server.

Comment: This was solved. But basically if I made changes to a file and saved it, those changes would not show on port 8000.

Answer (score 3):

If you look at the [SimpleHTTPServer Documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/simplehttpserver.html) it mentions how to use the module from the command line.

> The SimpleHTTPServer module can also be invoked directly using the -m switch of the interpreter with a port number argument.
>
> `python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000`

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by update? The files are hosted on a localhost server.

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8001
```

Comment: This should really be a comment rather than an answer, since we haven't fully understood the problem...

Comment: I addressed the port number in the answer though.

Answer (score 0):

You can run a SimpleHTTPServer from Terminal

If you want to host the files of **Desktop** then

```
cd Desktop
```

and then

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8001
```

Point your browser to localhost:8001.

From Python Docs:

> This serves the files relative to the current directory.